# How do I build a JMenu dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I am trying to build a `JMenu` dynamically right when clicking in it (I'm only getting an empty menu), below is my code.

```
    final JMenu JMWindows = new JMenu("Opened Windows");                
    JMWindows.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {          
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(JInternalFrame ji : desktop.getAllFrames())
            {
                JMWindows.add(ji.getTitle());
            }               
        }
    });
```

I've realized that the `actionperformed` is never called, the `JMenu` is inside a `JMenuBar`. What could be the problem ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You add `ActionListener` to `JMenu` this cannot be done for `JMenu` use [`MenuListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MenuListener.html) and set it via [`JMenu#addMenuListener(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#addMenuListener%28javax.swing.event.MenuListener%29)
- Also you need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on `JMenu` instance after adding/removing components from it or the changes will not be reflected (we could also call this on the containers instance i.e `JMenuBar` or `JFrame`, but we know only 1 specific `JMenu` will change so no need IMO).
- Please watch your variable naming schemes `JMWindow` should be `jmWindow`/`jMWindow` variables always begin with no caps and the 1st letter of every new word thereafter gets capitalized (besides for constants and `enums`).

Here is an example using `MenuListener`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

public class Test {

    private JDesktopPane jdpDesktop;
    private static int openFrameCount = 0;
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JInternalFrame Usage Demo");

    public Test() {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // A specialized layered pane to be used with JInternalFrames
        jdpDesktop = new JDesktopPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 500);
            }
        };


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            createFrame(); // Create first window
        }

        frame.setContentPane(jdpDesktop);

        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        // Make dragging faster by setting drag mode to Outline
        jdpDesktop.putClientProperty("JDesktopPane.dragMode", "outline");

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Frame");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("New IFrame");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                createFrame();
            }
        });
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);


        final JMenu jmWindows = new JMenu("Opened Windows");
        jmWindows.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent me) {
                jmWindows.removeAll();//remove previous opened window jmenuitems
                for (JInternalFrame ji : jdpDesktop.getAllFrames()) {
                    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(ji.getTitle());
                    jmWindows.add(menuItem);
                }

                jmWindows.revalidate();
                jmWindows.repaint();
                jmWindows.doClick();

            }

            @Override
            public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent me) {
            }

            @Override
            public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent me) {
            }
        });
        menuBar.add(jmWindows);


        return menuBar;
    }

    protected void createFrame() {
        Test.MyInternalFrame frame = new Test.MyInternalFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Every JInternalFrame must be added to content pane using JDesktopPane
        jdpDesktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;

        public MyInternalFrame() {
            super("IFrame #" + (++openFrameCount), true, // resizable
                    true, // closable
                    true, // maximizable
                    true);// iconifiable
            setSize(300, 300);
            // Set the window's location.
            setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition
                    * openFrameCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GuillaumePolet +1 true sorry about that cant remember where i saw that (updated post), and I was just warning OP as many people dont know standard variable naming schemes, never mind having to differentiate between variables and special variable naming schemes

Comment: doClick enters the run to infinite loop - should be removed

Answer (score 2):

You need to repaint and or validate your frame after adding or removing something. 
you can use the methods `repaint()` and `validate()` in your JFrame for this

Comment: I tried both, repaint and validate inside the actionperformed but it is not working...

I tried repainting and validating the container frame

Answer (score 1):

You missed defining a JMenuItem.

```
    final JMenu JMWindows = new JMenu("Opened Windows");                
    JMWindows.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {          
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(JInternalFrame ji : desktop.getAllFrames())
            {
                JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(ji.getTitle());
                JMWindows.add(menuItem);
            }               
        }
    });
```